# How to fix display problems with CKEditor?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

I have installed CKEditor 3.6.0.6, I have enabled some buttons as in image:

[CKEditor 3.6.0.6 in full size browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jg86.jpg)

However when I resize the browser smaller than the buttons zones, here is how is looking:
[image: CKEditor 3.6.0.6 in smaller size browser]

How can I brake CKEditor buttons to be displayed on multiple lines ? And why this behavior of CKEditor?

My browser Chrome 12.0.742.100. In Firefox 5 is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CK Editor supports to manage toolbars. In toolbars you can manage Buttons. [See the guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar).